# Verify that $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec E = \vec 0$ and $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec E = 0 \text { for all }\vec r \ne \vec 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to solve this exercise, but I'm not getting started.

Be an electric charged particle Q > 0
located at the origin of the coordinate system. So, the electric field strength in $$\vec r = (x,y,z)$$ it's
$$\vec E = K\frac{Q}{r^2}\hat e_r$$

beeind r the unit vector
$$ r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

and K is a constant that depends on the medium where the particle is located. Verify that:

(a) $$\vec{\nabla} \times \vec E = \vec 0$$
(b) $$\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec E = 0 \text { for all }\vec r \ne \vec 0$$

Comment: [help](https://brilliant.org/wiki/maxwells-equations/#:~:text=Maxwell's%20equations%20are%20a%20set,proportional%20to%20the%20charge%20enclosed.) is here

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know the expressions for $\vec\nabla$ (i.e. curl and divergence) in spherical coordinates?

Comment: so, i know in the question (a) it's a differential form of faraday's law and the (b) it's differential form of gauss's law and i know this expression, but i dont know how to verify

Comment: So, you have a given vector field, expressed in spherical ccordinates, and two differential equations that you should verify. You can have a look at the expressions foir curl and divergence e.g. her: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates . Can you apply these expressions to your vector field?